# Print when user inputs 'y'

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I cannot seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong in the following simple code. It's supposed to print out 0..9 if`y` is entered and exit otherwise.

```
void userInput(char *in);

int main()
{

    int i;
    char c;

    setbuf(stdout, 0);

    userInput(&c);

    while(c == 'y'){
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            printf("\n%c", i);
        }
        userInput(&c);
    }
    printf("\nGoodbye!");
    return 0;
}


void userInput(char *in)
{
    printf("\nPrint numbers 0 to 9? (y/n) ");
    scanf("%c",in);
    fflush(stdin);

    while ( (*in !='y') || (*in != 'n') ){
        printf("\nUnknown command. Press (y/n)");
        scanf("%c",in);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's not doing what it's supposed to, what is it doing? What's the missing behavior?

Comment: Do not call `fflush(stdin);` - it's non-portable and results in UB on most platforms.

Comment: `(*in !='y') || (*in != 'n')` --> `(*in !='y') && (*in != 'n')`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [format specifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Type) `%c`, which prints out the ASCII character with the given value. [ASCII characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart) 0 through 9 are all unprintable control characters or various forms of whitespace.

You want to use `%d` to print out a decimal integer instead.

```
printf("\n%d", i);
```

By the way, you should also put the newlines (`\n`) at the end of the strings, not the beginning. The enter key will have already advance the line after the user typed in `y`, and stdio is line bufferred by default, which means it may not print anything until you get to a newline. That means that you may not see the prompt (as there is no trailing newline), nor the "Goodbye!" message. If you do not want to have a line break after your prompt, instead of adding a newline to the end, you can call `fflush(stdout)` to ensure that you flush the buffer, printint it to the terminal.

*edit*: Ah, I notice you disabled buffering of stdout up above. That works too, but it's generally preferable to leave the default buffering and explicitly flush when you need to.